# ¿Cómo insertar datos nulos a mi consulta para completar mis datos?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core

realizo una consulta a la base de datos para conocer por cliente los trabajos asignados (en la base se llama `Carpetas`) agrupados por año y luego cuento por mes. El resultado es en formato JSON.

**Consulta**

```
var query = from g in _context.Carpetas
            where g.ClienteId == id
            group g by g.FechaAlta.Year into grupo
            select new
                    {
                        periodo = grupo.Key,
                        data = grupo.GroupBy(s => s.FechaAlta.Month).Select(s => new
                        {
                            mes = s.Key,
                            cuenta = s.Count()
                        })
                    };
```

**Salida**

```
[{"periodo":1998,"data":[{"mes":8,"cuenta":157},{"mes":10,"cuenta":10},{"mes":11,"cuenta":2}]},{"periodo":1999,"data":[{"mes":2,"cuenta":3}]},{"periodo":2011,"data":[{"mes":5,"cuenta":1}]}]
```

La finalidad es graficar con Highchart. Los años son las series y en categorias los meses del año.

El problema está en que no todos los meses se asignan trabajos, entonces necesito insertar datos nulos en las fechas faltantes.

Encontré dos post: [éste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086120/linq-group-by-date-include-empty-days-without-using-join) y [éste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468637/filling-in-missing-dates-using-a-linq-group-by-date-query)

Por lo que probe este código donde luego hago `Union()`

**Datos nulos**

```
var añoMinimo = new DateTime(1998,1,1);
var añoHoy = DateTime.Now;

var range = GetDateRange(añoMinimo, añoHoy).OrderBy(s => s.Month); //GENERO DATOS NULOS POR AÑO AGRUPADO POR MES DESDE 1998 HASTA LA FECHA

var rangoFecha = from d in range
                             group d by d.Year into grupo
                             select new
                             {
                                 periodo = grupo.Key,
                                 data = grupo.GroupBy(s => s.Month).Select(s => new
                                 {
                                     mes = s.Key,
                                     cuenta = 0
                                 })
                             };
    var resultado = query.Union(rangoFecha).OrderBy(s => s.periodo);
```

**El resultado después de usar `Union()`**

```
[{"periodo":1998,"data":[{"mes":8,"cuenta":157},{"mes":10,"cuenta":10},{"mes":11,"cuenta":2}]},{"periodo":1998,"data":[{"mes":1,"cuenta":0},{"mes":2,"cuenta":0},{"mes":3,"cuenta":0},{"mes":4,"cuenta":0},{"mes":5,"cuenta":0},{"mes":6,"cuenta":0},{"mes":7,"cuenta":0},{"mes":8,"cuenta":0},{"mes":9,"cuenta":0},{"mes":10,"cuenta":0},{"mes":11,"cuenta":0},{"mes":12,"cuenta":0}]}}] //LO CORTO PARA NO HACER TAN LARGO
```

Como se puede observar no se une como quisiera, ya que crea dos series con el año 1998. Primero con los meses que tienen datos y luego con los nulos repitiendo los meses que ya tengo.

Se que estoy muy cerca pero estoy trabado acá.
Alguna sugerencia?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es tener un lista de objetos con anio,mes,value vacío y otro igual con datos y luego hacer un union o concat.

```
query.Concat(rangoFecha.Where(l2 => !query.Contains(l2))).ToList()
```